# No visible @interface for 'Contact' declares the selector 'initWithName:thumbnail:email:'

Tags: ios, objective-c

What's wrong on my code?

I've looked on google for more information about the error but could not find any solution to my problem . Could anyone help me solve this problem?

The error occurs in these lines :

1. self = [self initWithName:dic[@"name"] thumbnail:dic[@"thumbnail"]
   email:dic[@"email"]];
2. self = [self initWithName:@"Undifined"
       thumbnail:@"Undifined" email:@"Undifined"];

**Contact.h**

```
//
//  Contact.h
//  Teste
//
//  Created by Samuel Neiva on 13/04/16.
//  Copyright (c) 2016 Samuel Neiva. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Contact : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *thumbnail;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *email;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)aName
         thumbnail:(NSString *)aThumbnail
             photo:(NSString *)aEmail;

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dic;

@end
```

**Contact.m**

```
//
//  Contact.m
//  Teste
//
//  Created by Samuel Neiva on 13/04/16.
//  Copyright (c) 2016 Samuel Neiva. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Contact.h"

@implementation Contact

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dic {
    self = [self initWithName:dic[@"name"] thumbnail:dic[@"thumbnail"] email:dic[@"email"]];
    return self;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [self initWithName:@"Undifined" thumbnail:@"Undifined" email:@"Undifined"];
    return self;
}

//The designated initializer
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)aName
         thumbnail:(NSString *)aThumbnail
             photo:(NSString *)aEmail {

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.name = aName;
        self.thumbnail = aThumbnail;
        self.email = aEmail;
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@", self.name, self.description];
}


@end
```

Comment: This must be a copy-paste error: `photo:(NSString *)aEmail` -> `email:(NSString *)aEmail`

Answer (score 0):

`Contact` doesn't declare that method, just like the warning says. It declares `initWithName:thumbnail:photo`.